# Access a button's properties inside its click event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

A button:

```
<button class='button pasteButton' id='pasteButton1'>Button Label</button>
```

The button's click handler:

```
$(document).on('click','.pasteButton',function(e){

    //alert("paste clicked");
    alert(this.id);

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

I'm able to get the button's `id` inside the click handler with the above code. How may I get the button's value (i.e., "Button Label") or some other property inside the click handler?

(And while we're on the subject, why is it that with jQuery sometimes we need to do: `this` (e.g., above) and at other times we need to do: `$(this)` ... is there a simple explanation of the difference please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to retrieve the text, either access the [`textContent` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) on the [DOM element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element):

```
this.textContent // Button Label
```

Or use the jQuery [`.text()` method](http://api.jquery.com/text/):

```
$(this).text() // Button Label
```

---

> Why is it that that with jQuery sometimes we need to do: `this` (e.g., above) and at other times we need to do: `$(this)`

In this case, `this` is a [DOM element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element), whereas `$(this)` is a [jQuery object](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/).

Native DOM element have properties, such as `value`, `id`, `textContent`.

```
this.id // pasteButton1
this.textContent // Button Label
```

It's worth pointing out that you *can't* use jQuery methods directly on DOM elements, which is why you wrap `this` with `$()` in order to turn it into a jQuery object.

```
$(this).prop('id') // pasteButton1
$(this).text() // Button Label
```

Comment: Thank you very very much. Really clarified things really well. A huge help. I wish some of the nomenclature wasn't so different between DOM and jQuery. (E.g., in HTML I think we refer to a button element's label as it's value). And in the link you provided for the documentation of the `.text()` method, the word "button" doesn't appear on the page, so,  for a semi-beginner such as myself, it becomes really difficult to understand the connection.

Comment: @user1883050 I'm glad that helped. Like most things, I think it just takes practice :)

Comment: '1' for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#mButton").click(function(){
       alert("name:"+ $(this).attr("value"));
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input id="mButton" type = "button" value="submit"/>

</body>
</html>
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/9czct416/)